# Calculating the efficiency of glass

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, 3d

Is the integral in the meme picture correct when it comes to calculating the efficiency of the glass? Assuming the cup is a perfect frustum of a cone.

[image]

Comment: Probably not since if it is it's making assumptions about the glass that we're not given (e.g. $\pi$ is probably popping up by assuming the glass is made of a truncated cone).

Comment: At the very least paste the picture and not a link, or use latex

Comment: @Eevee Trainer If we are to assume the cup is a frustum, is the integral correct?

Comment: No, it’s not right. First off, there is no $h$ (the variable of integration) in any of the integrals, and if the glass were a cylinder with $r_1=r_2$, all of the integrals diverge. Even if the $h_2$s are changed to $h$s, the numerator is zero when $h_1=h_2$, which should represent a full glass, not an empty glass.

Answer (score 1):

The two point formula for a line gives us
$$\frac{r-r_1}{h-0}=\frac{r_2-r_1}{h_2-0}$$
or
$$r=r_1+\frac{r_2-r_1}{h_2}h$$
Which can be checked by substituting in $h=0$ and $h=h_2$.
Then the volume up to $h_1$ is
$$V_1=\int_0^{h_1}\pi\left[r_1+\frac{r_2-r_1}{h_2}h\right]^2dh$$
And up to $h_2$ is
$$V_2=\int_0^{h_2}\pi\left[r_1+\frac{r_2-r_1}{h_2}h\right]^2dh$$
This is not equivalent to the formula in the picture. Note that in that case the integrands are constant, so the volume would be proportional to $h$ which only works for a cylinder $r_2=r_1$ in which case the expressions contain division by zero.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I only wish I could upvote you publicly but my reputation disallows it.